# Metaphosphoric acid and water in cold

Tags: acid-base, redox, temperature

Consider this redox reaction:

$$\ce{3PCl3 + 2HNO3 (conc.) + 5H2O → 2NO + 3[HPO3] + 9HCl}$$

The metaphosphoric acid is taken in square brackets, because I have doubts about it. As I know, this reaction is endothermic. Is it possible the metaphosphoric acid is formed in this reaction (there is a water in left part of equation, metaphosphoric acid may react with it, but the temperature is decreasing)? Are there some real environmental condition where this reaction is possible? Or it's only the orthophosphoric acid is formed?

Comment: Don't add water (or rather, add _less_ water), and this thing will have no choice but to go to $\ce{HPO3}$ and even less hydrated forms.

Comment: Can you clarify, is this an actual reaction or one that you are proposing?

Comment: That one was written by me on exam. I do not really propose what is the real  yield of that reaction, but i'm interested in conditions that may move the balance to right side and realize the metaphosphoric acid (not orthophosphoric).