Metaphosphate or Metaphosphite?
What is the proper name for Ca(PO3)2 ?

Calcium Metaphosphite
...or
Calcium Metaphosphate
...or
Calcium Metaphosphonate
Edit:
The image depicting the structure was taken from:
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Calcium-metaphosphate

This structure is not correct.

For the correct structure and a method of preparation, see https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270188012922.

You might want to see: Structure of calcium metaphosphate Ca(PO3)2 by W. Rothammel, H. Burzlaff and R. Specht

Such structure was depicted here:  https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Calcium-metaphosphate

Well, didn't I mention under your other question that Pubchem isn't a good source? Also now you're referring there to the paper mentioned by Nilay...

$\ce{Ca(PO3)2}$ is a salt due to the neutralization of the base $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ by the acid $\ce{HPO3}$. This acid is due to the loss of $1 $ $\ce{H2O}$ from the "regular" phosphoric acid $\ce{H3PO4}$. So the acid $\ce{HPO3}$ (or its polymer $\ce{(HPO3)_n}$) contains a $\ce{P}$ atom with oxidation number $+5$. All acids containing $\ce{P}$ atoms with an oxidation number equal to $+5$ have a name finishing in -ic. And their salts are finished in -ate. They may have different prefixes. So, $\ce{Ca(PO3)2}$ has a name in -ate". It is called calcium metaphosphate.

There is no "HPO3" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphosphate

The name, though, is correct.

HPO3 exist in polymerized form: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170640/metaphosphoric-acid-can-it-exist-as-monomer

@Maurice:  The PO3 component compound is named as the "Phosphonate" in the link below:  https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Calcium-metaphosphate

If "phosponate" is correct, shouldn't the entire compound be named "Calcium Metaphosphonate" ?

The word "phosphonate"* is not correct. According to Wikipedia, phosphonates are organophosphorus compounds containing a covalent bond between the $\ce{P}$ atom and a $\ce{H}$ or a $\ce{C}$ atom (from an alkyl or aryl group)

@GeorgeRobinson - if you read the compound description of phosphonate on the page you linked, it's clearly a mix-up. As the description of the compound notes, "phosphonate" refers either to $\ce{H2PO3-}$ or $\ce{HPO3^2-}$, ie the anions that result from deporotonation of phosphonic acid ($\ce{H3PO3}$).

As explained by Maurice, the key difference bstween "-ate" and "ite" for oxysalts is the oxidation state of the central atom to which the oxygen is attached. Your compound has phosphorus(V) like the ordinary calcium (ortho)phosphate $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$, therefore it also will be a phosphate, specifically calcium metaphosphate.
Metaphosphite, with phosphorous(III), would properly be $\ce{PO2^-}$ or a polymer thereof. Such an anion is unknown as salts but has been incorporated as a ligand in rhenium complexes[1]. As a ligand in these complexes, the metaphosphite ion bonds to the metal through the phosphorus atom and acts similarly to nitrite ion coordinated through the nitrogen atom. Facile reduction of the rhenium in this complex from $\ce{Re(III)}$ to $\ce{Re(II)}$ and $\ce{Re(I)}$ is demonstrated.
Reference

J. Abbenseth, F. Wätjen, M. Finger, S. Schneider, "The Metaphosphite (PO2−) Anion as a Ligand". Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. 2020, 59, 23574. https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.202011750.

